# Cholesky factorization, why $A = L L^*$ instead of $A = U U^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

For a positive definite matrix $A$, we have the Cholesky decomposition

$$A = L L^*  ,$$

where $L $ is a lower triangular matrix. I am curious why not

$$A = U U^*,$$

where $U $ is an upper triangular matrix. Is it not possible or is it useless?

Comment: It's the same thing...